# Implementing media player in Android application

Tags: android

I am developing an application in which I have to perform three functions play, record and pause an audio file.

Has anyone implemented it before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [`MediaPlayer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) or [`AudioTrack`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html) for playback. The difference is that `MediaPlayer` can play several audio formats directly from file (or in some cases even from remote URL), while `AudioTrack` plays only from raw LPCM buffer,

For recording take a look at [`MediaRecorder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) or [`AudioRecord`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html). The difference is that `MediaRecorder` records audio and video to `.3gp`, while `AudioRecord` gives you only audio as raw LPCM buffers. The `AudioRecord` data can be used to create `.wav` files (though some extra code is required for this).

Comment: ok,,,,,do u have any example or source code,,if yes,,can u place over here,,